# Can't fetch packages during dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade from 18.04.1 to 18.04.2 and I'm getting the following errors which cause the upgrade to abort

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-missing
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport apport-gtk python3-apport python3-problem-report
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 225 kB of archives.
After this operation, 10.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-problem-report all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
Ign:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-apport all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apport all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apport-gtk all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-problem-report all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python3-apport all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apport all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 apport-gtk all 2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/python3-problem-report_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/python3-apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/apport_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apport/apport-gtk_2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

Yes, I did run sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade although obviously upgrade fails on the same packages.

I can find the packages on launchpad.net or ubuntu.pkgs.org but I'm not sure how to redirect the source to point to these repositories instead of looking where they don't exist. These are the launchpad links.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/python3-problem-report/2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/amd64/python3-apport/2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/2.20.9-0ubuntu7.3/+build/15147751

This is the output of 'sudo apt-get update'

```
Hit:1 http://linux-packages.resilio.com/resilio-sync/deb resilio-sync InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                               
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                                                              
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                                             
Ign:5 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist InRelease                                                                                                                                      
Get:6 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist Release [2,040 B]                                                                                                                              
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                             
Get:8 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist Release.gpg [490 B]                                                                                                                            
Ign:9 https://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/ InRelease                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                       
Get:11 https://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/ Release [1,479 B]                                                                                                                                             
Ign:12 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease                                                                                                                                       
Get:13 https://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/ Release.gpg [819 B]                                                                                                                
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                                                                          
Hit:15 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release                                                                                         
Hit:16 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:8 http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist Release.gpg
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages         
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages                              
Ign:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages                            
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages                                  
Ign:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages      
Ign:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages        
Ign:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages                         
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages                               
Ign:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages                         
Ign:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages                           
Ign:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages   
Err:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main armhf Packages         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/restricted armhf Packages   
Ign:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe armhf Packages     
Ign:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse armhf Packages   
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Ign:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages 
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [480 kB]
Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages [284 kB]
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [561 kB]
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en [207 kB]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66.6 kB]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [123 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages [6,488 B]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Ign:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages
Ign:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Ign:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted armhf Packages
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Get:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages [187 kB]
Ign:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe armhf Packages
Ign:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:71 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:72 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:73 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:71 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:72 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:73 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Ign:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
Ign:71 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:72 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:73 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Err:42 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Ign:71 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/restricted armhf Packages
Ign:72 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe armhf Packages
Ign:73 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse armhf Packages
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist Release: The following signatures were invalid: 492EAFE8CD016A07919F1D2B9ECBEC467F0CEB10
E: The repository 'http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-apt-config/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-5.7/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'mysql-tools/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Please add the complete output of a successful apt update. Since your system is demanding old (removed) packages, I suspect your apt update wasn't actually successful.

Comment: @N0rbert I tried that solution, I removed mysql and mongodb as well and I'm still getting errors on packages that can't be fetched when I try to do an update, I have a bunch of other software repositories enabled, I may need to crawl through those and see if one of them is causing the fetch errors

Comment: Why do you have `armhf` in the outputs? What is the CPU architecture of your system?

Comment: @N0rbert It's x86, I'm trying to figure out what is calling for those dirs, I'm disabling one repository at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should completely disable non-x86 repositories in your system.

You can check problematic lines by the following command:

```
grep -r "^deb.*armhf" /etc/apt/sources.list* --include="*.list"
```

Then disable such repositories manually from *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) or by manual editing of related `*.list` files.

Do not forget to run `sudo apt-get update` after changes.

If you are sure that `armhf` does not found in `*.list` - then remove the `armhf` architecture with command below:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
```

---

The last error message about `http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart` may be removed by disabling this repo. It seems that you do not need it, as your 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver) do not use `upstart` anymore and it is `systemd`-based. Also please note that 18.04 LTS already has [MongoDB 3.6.3](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/bionic/mongodb), while the problematic repository [provides 2.6.x](http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/README-3.0).

Comment: I blew away mongo db completely from my system, I ran the grep command and it returns nothing, I can't find any references to arm although I wasn't running update after each repository that I disabled, I'll go through them again running that after each change

Comment: I did what I could to restore the default repositories
sources.list just contains this now and I disabled all other repositories but I'm still getting armhf fetch errors

`deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-security main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main`

Comment: Then we can try to make search query wider - i.e. `grep -r arm /etc/apt/sources.list* --include="*.list"` or remove the CPU architecture - `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf`.

Comment: I specified the architecture in the sources.list file like this [arch=amd64] and it updated and is now running the dist-upgrade, should I still do the remove-architecture command?

Comment: You should not set `[arch=amd64]` as modern 64-bit distro is multilib, so may require i386 packages as well. So consider to remove `[arch=amd64]` and then run `sudo dpkg --remove-architecture armhf` followed by `sudo apt-get update`.